# Postar um comentário e exibir em seguida sem refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**Atualizado 5**

Bom dia pessoal, estou tentando criar um sistema de comentários igual ao http://demo.hazzardweb.net/comments/

abaixo temos o código javascript que envia o formulário e em seguida adiciona o comentário, está quase tudo certo, falta modificar alguma coisa, pois tenho muitos formulários com tal id, como faz para enviar cada formulário com cada id?

**Aqui é o código JavaScript para enviar tudo para o PHP:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.commentform').submit(function() {
    var comment_publication_id = $(this).find('input[name=comment_publication_id]').val();
    var comment = $(this).find('textarea[name=comment]').val();
    var dataString = 'comment=' + comment + '&comment_publication_id=' + comment_publication_id;
    var divtoload = '#commentsforpublication' + comment_publication_id;
    var sendcommentbutton = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
    var commenttextarea = $(this).find('textarea[name=comment]');
    if (comment == ""){
    alert("Não pode deixar em branco!");
    } else
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sendcomment.php",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(mydata) {
      $(sendcommentbutton).attr("disabled", true);
      $(commenttextarea).attr("disabled", true);
      $("#" + comment_publication_id + ".commentform").prepend('<div id="loading"><img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"></div>');
      $("textarea#commentto" + comment_publication_id).val('');
      setTimeout(function(){
      $("#loading").remove();
      var addcomment = '<div> "Exemplo, coloca mydata.nome do array que está no php " </div>';
      $(divtoload).append(addcomment);
      $(divtoload).find(".commentbox:last").hide().fadeIn('slow').slideDown("normal");
      $(sendcommentbutton).attr("disabled", false);
      $(commenttextarea).attr("disabled", false);
      }, 4000);
      }
    });
return false;
  });
});
```

**sendcomment.php (Aqui eu faço o INSERT e retorno os valores para o JavaScript):**

```
mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO questioncomments (comment_question_id,comment_autor_id,comment,comment_datetime) VALUES ('$comment_question_id','$comment_autor_id','$comment',NOW())");

$last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);

$questioncomments = "SELECT questioncomments.*, login.* FROM questioncomments INNER JOIN login ON questioncomments.comment_autor_id = login.user_id WHERE comment_id = $last_insert_id LIMIT 1";
$commentsresult = $conexao->query($questioncomments);
while ($rowcomments = $commentsresult->fetch_assoc()) {
$nome = $rowcomments["Nome"];   
$comment_question_id = $rowcomments["comment_question_id"];
$commentdatetime = date('d/m/Y \à\s H:i', strtotime($rowcomments["comment_datetime"])); 
}

//  array
$my = array(

 'comment_id'=>$last_insert_id,
 'user_id'=>$comment_autor_id,
 'Nome'=>$nome,
 'comment_date_time'=>$commentdatetime

);

// converto ele com a função json_encode

    $myJSON = json_encode($my);

// coloco na tela o objeto javascript

    echo($myJSON);
```

**Formulário para enviar o comentário:**

```
<form method="post" class="commentform" id=" (Aqui é a ID da publicação) ">  
  <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" class="sendcomment">
  <input type="hidden" name="comment_question_id" id="comment_question_id" value=" (Aqui é a ID da publicação) ">  
  <button type="submit" class="sendcomment-button">Enviar comentário</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Seguindo o que o Anderson Nunes falou é só você usar Json, basicamente você vai dar commit no html para o php usando Jquery e fazer com que o comentário vá para o php e o mesmo dê um retorno para o html e você popule um elemento html sem dar refresh.

Comment: Editei toda a sua pergunta. Estude a edição para não cometer os mesmo erros em perguntas futuras, mantenha-as bem formatadas.

Comment: Kevin, retirei o excesso de negrito e citações de sua pergunta, veja na Central de Ajuda e neste tópico http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas como formatar suas perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Obrigado gente, por me corrigir, estou me adaptando ao stackoverflow :)

Comment: So acho que seria interessante você manter a pergunta original, a pessoa entra na pergunta, e vê na sua resposta a resposta que você adotou e não entende o escopo da sua pergunta...

Comment: Um dos recursos que você pode(e deve!) usar é o de selecionar a melhor resposta

Comment: desculpe havia esquecido de selecionar, e penso que a pessoa que ver a questão e que entende o minimo  de php, ou pelo menos tem vontade, vai pesquisar sobre como enviar formulário com ajax, só isto, pois a questão foi praticamente baseada nele.

Comment: Reverti a última edição, pois você tinha removido o mais importante: a pergunta! Aproveito pra recomendar uma passada na [help] pra entender melhor como funciona o site. As perguntas não são como um bate-papo com especialistas, com muitos vaivéns entre os interlocutores. O formato é de perguntas diretas com respostas diretas. Tente sempre dividir o seu problema em problemas menores, e perguntar separadamente sobre cada um deles. Assim o conteúdo tem mais chances de ser útil para outras pessoas além de você. Ir transformando a pergunta enquanto você vai mexendo no código não funciona bem aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou dar um exemplo - explicação - superficial para passar a ideia. Basicamente você tem uma *DIV-PAI* para englobar os comentários. Quando submeter o formulário via *AJAX*, basta criar o elemento formatado no inicio usando `prepend` usando o ID do comentário como referência para remoção.

<kbd><kbd>comentário 3</kbd>


  <kbd>comentário 2</kbd>


  <kbd>comentário 1</kbd></kbd>

---

<sub>**Insert**</sub>

```
$(function(){
    $('.commentform').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            url    : 'comment.php',
            data   : data,
            success: function( ID )
            {
                $('#content').prepend( '
                <div id="IDComment_' + ID + '">
                    <p>' + $( '#comment' ).val() + '</p>
                    <button id="delete" class="' + ID + '">deletar</button>
                </div>' )
            }
        });
    });
});
```

O insert envia os dados e recebe o ID do comentário para criação do elemento com o botão de remoção e o texto do comentário. Usando `prepend` o comentário enviado aparece no topo da *DIV-PAI*.

---

<sub>**Delete**</sub>

```
$(function(){
    $('#delete').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST',
            url    : 'comment.php',
            data   : data,
            success: function( $(this).attr('class') )
            {
                $('#IDComment_' + $(this).attr('class')).remove()
            }
        });
    });
});
```

O delete vai pegar o atributo *class* contendo o ID do comentário e remover o elemento em caso de *success*.

---

### Considerações...

Esse é um exemplo simples, basicamente só a ideia. Fazer o js criar e formatar o HTML diminui a quantidade de dados trafegando. Por outro lado você tem no js elementos que são parte de uma *view*, o que acaba tornando redundante. Você pode formatar o bloco do comentário no PHP e enviar como json. Casa caso é um caso.

Removi as variáveis do js para deixar o código menor, creio que essa etapa não seja mistério.

Comment: @Kevinmtk, Se estiver usando `PDO`, basta usar `lastInsertId` para enviar o ID do comentário. Você não sabe fazer um insert no MYSQL?

Comment: Não vejo problema em relação a isso. Sobre [**insert-id**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: @Kevinmt Bom, `append` cria no fim e `prepend` cria no inicio. Você escolhe onde deseja inserir o comentário, só dei a referência do elemento. Qualquer requisição via AJAX só precisa que o PHP dê um simples *echo* - em caso de string.

Comment: Sim, `echo $last_ins_id` vai enviar o ID. O exemplo que dei é uma base para você adaptar o que já tem feito - não é complicado. Qualquer dúvida basta comentar, qualquer um pode dar um suporte aqui.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23485/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-kevin-mtk).

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho interessante você não atribuir no formulário o código do comentário. Seria interessante você tirar o bloco. Dê uma olhada no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.commentform').submit(function() {
    var data = $('.commentform').serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "sendcomment.php",
      data: data,
      success: function() {
        var tab = document.getElementById("table");
        var novoComentario = document.createElement("td");
        novoComentario.textContent = "Teste de comentario";
        tab.appendChild(novoComentario);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form method='post' action='#' class='commentform' id='commentquestion$question_id'>
  <input type='text' name='comment' class='sendcomment' required></input>
  <button type='submit' class='sendcomment-button'>Enviar comentário</button>
</form>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Comentário 1</td>
    <td>Comentário 2</td>
    <td>Comentário 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Isso é até bem simples de fazer em ajax. vou dar um exemplo em qual se basear:

http://blog.clares.com.br/utilizando-metodo-post-do-jquery-php/

Primeiro você usa o jQuery para enviar os dados para um php, este mesmo php você salva no banco e já da um `echo` no final dele com a informação que você precisa. Veja que no exemplo que te passei, tem a variável `data`, ela recebe o retorno deste `echo` do seu php.

Agora, digamos que você queira exibir o que tem na variável `data` (que é o retorno do seu php, ou seja, o `echo` que você deu lá) em um `input`. É simples, basta trocar o `alert(data)` que tem no código do exemplo por algo assim:

```
$('#id_do_seu_input').val(data)
```

Você estará salvando no banco e exibindo sem *refresh* da página. Claro, o exemplo em questão apenas envia para o php e recebe o retorno, no php você terá que fazer todo o esquema de salvar em um banco de dados, que acredito você sabe fazer.

Se tiver mais problemas me avise que tento ajudar de outra forma.

Comment: Se não der certo informe aqui que explico melhor, mas o principio é este. Faz o teste do exemplo da forma que esta aqui e depois adapta a sua necessidade com mysql.